# Why using this instead $(this) in jQuery Plugin?

Tags: jquery

I am reading a tutorial [here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

the basic plugin it create is like this:

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$( "a" ).greenify();
```

My question is what's the difference if I use:

```
$(this).css();
```

instead of using

```
this.css();
```

Comment: It says why right on the page you linked to: _"Notice that to use `.css()`, another method, we use `this`, not `$( this )`. This is because our greenify function is a part of the same object as `.css()`."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is already a jQuery object, so it's not necessary to call `$()`. If you give `$()` a jQuery object as the argument, it creates a new jQuery object containing the same elements. So `this` and `$(this)` will be equivalent, but there's unnecessary overhead in making the copy.

You need to use `$(this)` when `this` is a DOM element rather than a jQuery object. For instance, in event handlers, `this` is the DOM element that the event was triggered on, not a jQuery wrapper for the element.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a jQuery plug-in method, `this` is already the host jQuery object.  So, doing `$(this)` will work, but it's redundant (creates yet a new jQuery object with the same DOM elements in it) and thus is wasted code.  So, this works fine:

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};
```

This is true for all jQuery plug-in methods.

---

However, in other contexts like inside an event handler such as this:

```
$("myButton").click(function(e) {
   // this is the DOM element
   $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

`this` is just the DOM element so you need to do `$(this)` if you want a jQuery object to work with.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the call on an object, as you do here

```
$( "a" ).greenify();
```

then inside the function `this` will point to the object.

That is not particular to jQuery, that is just how Javascript objects work.

So in this case, `this` will be `$("a")`, i.e. already a jQuery object (you can wrap it in `$()` again, that won't hurt, but it is redundant).

In other situations (such as when interacting with the DOM directly), `this` may be something else. If it is a DOM node and you want to use it with jQuery, you have to "upgrade it", by wrapping it in `$()`.

Answer (score 1):

In that specific case, `this` is already a JQuery object, as shown here :

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};
```

Notice that `greenify` is defined as a function in JQuery.

In other cases, using `$(this)` might be necessary because `this` might refer to the HTML DOM object, rather than a JQuery object.